# Email Studio - Can you create an email in an external platform and delivery it via the MC API?

Tags: email, api

We've got a series of internal tools, largely aggregated from a workflow perspective.   Anyone know if it's possible if we create an email in our content creation tool and deliver to MC Email Studio via the API?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can. We do this in my organization. You can send the html of the email (and text version also, if you want), specify a target Data Extension, choose a Publication List, assign the email to a campaign, send a test send, and schedule the actual send time all through the API without using the UI. Or, you can just upload the email content itself through the API and handle the deployment through the UI.

That said, each use case is a little different and there are a number of different steps involved (including potentially both SOAP and REST calls).